# undefined reference glBindVertexArrayOES,glGenVertexArraysOES,glDeleteVertexArraysOES in eclipse

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

Trying to compile C++ code with Android NDK but these errors wont go away

```
undefined reference to glBindVertexArrayOES
undefined reference to glGenVertexArraysOES
undefined reference to glDeleteVertexArraysOES
```

In .mk file wrote

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog -lz  -landroid -lEGL
```

All other function are found perfectly, do i need to declare anything to make these work?

Comment: Have you considered that your implementation of OpenGL ES doesn't support OES_vertex_array_object?

Comment: In glext.h i see GL_API void GL_APIENTRY glBindVertexArrayOES (GLuint array);
GL_API void GL_APIENTRY glDeleteVertexArraysOES (GLsizei n, const GLuint *arrays);
GL_API void GL_APIENTRY glGenVertexArraysOES (GLsizei n, GLuint *arrays);

Answer (score 2):

This functions are not in base opengl es specification, so they are not defined by default, but offered as extensions.

If the device you use supports this extension, you can get the phsical address of the functions and use it by a function pointer.

it should be looking like this:

```
PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC glGenVertexArraysOES;
PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYOESPROC glBindVertexArrayOES;
PFNGLDELETEVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC glDeleteVertexArraysOES;
PFNGLISVERTEXARRAYOESPROC glIsVertexArrayOES;

glGenVertexArraysOES = (PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC)eglGetProcAddress ( "glGenVertexArraysOES" );
glBindVertexArrayOES = (PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYOESPROC)eglGetProcAddress ( "glBindVertexArrayOES" );
glDeleteVertexArraysOES = (PFNGLDELETEVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC)eglGetProcAddress ( "glDeleteVertexArraysOES" );
glIsVertexArrayOES = (PFNGLISVERTEXARRAYOESPROC)eglGetProcAddress ( "glIsVertexArrayOES" );
```

than you can use the functions. Just not forget this binding happens on runtime, so checking if this functions are supported is a good idea. If device does not support, the pointers will be 0.

Comment: Yeh. glBindVertexArrayOES and glGenVertexArraysOES work fine. But when i use glDeleteVertexArraysOES game crashed =/